# Injecting many decorated instances with Guice -- on mixing HessianServlet with Guice

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, guice, hessian

Given the following code in a Guice servlet module `configureServlets()`:

```
serve("/a").with(new Decorator(new A()));
serve("/b").with(new Decorator(new B()));
...
serve("/z").with(new Decorator(new Z()));
...
```

What would be the best / easiest solution to properly inject all this? (i.e. injecting fields in the various decorated classes A, B, C...)

I was thinking using named providers, but I would prefer not having to define a new provider class for each A, B, C... The ideal solution would be thus generic.

---

**ON MIXING HESSIAN WITH GUICE...**

To help precise the question, the real code uses web-services with Hessian. After digging on the net there is currently **no** proper answer on this problem (I've seen many ugly hacks), and the solution given by *Guillaume* fits the bill on this precise case.

To summarize the original problem: to implement a web-service using Hessian, one must implement an `HessianServlet`, which is a `GenericServlet`; however Guice can only bind `HttpServlet`. The trick was thus to implement a thin wrapper `HessianHttpServlet`:

```
class HessianHttpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public HessianHttpServlet(HessianServlet hessianServlet) {
        this.hessianServlet = hessianServlet;
    }
    @Override public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        hessianServlet.init(config);
    }
    @Override public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {                 
        hessianServlet.service(request, response);
    }
}
```

And calling:

```
serve("/a").with(new HessianHttpServlet(new WebServiceA()));
```

The complete solution is thus in that case to inject `WebService`*X* :

```
void configureServlet() {
    serve("/a").with(new HessianHttpServlet(inject(new WebServiceA())));
    serve("/b").with(new HessianHttpServlet(inject(new WebServiceB())));
    ...
    serve("/z").with(new HessianHttpServlet(inject(new WebServiceZ())));
}
private HessianServlet inject(HessianServlet hessianServlet) {
    requestInjection(hessianServlet);
    return hessianServlet;
}
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is this Decorator thing? Can't you just bind serve("/a").with(A.class)? Injection on A will then be automatically done. Same goes for B, C , Z. I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Well, the decorator is here to add a common functionality on top of  all the decorated classes A,B,C... Adding directly this functionality to A, B, C would break the advantage of having this decorator. Furthermore, the decorator could be changed dynamically; here I've taken a simple example with only one decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `requestInjection(Object instance)` on each of your decorators.

Comment: In my case, I only need injecting decorated instances, so calling `serve("/a").with(new Decorator(injected(new A())))` would do it, with `injected()` an helper function just calling `requestInjection()` and returning the instance. But somehow I'm feeling bad writing this and I have the impression that this is misusing DI a bit.

Comment: I think I understand what you feel. You would like some way to say serve("/a*").with(Decorator.class).using(A.class); (syntax is not correct but it kinda express what you would want). Unfortunately my knowledge of Guice does not reach that extent.

Answer (score 1):

I created a little open source project which enables easy integration of hessian and guice. You can use annotation based configuration like this:
WebService:

```
@HessianWebService
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    ...
}
```

Guice configuration:

```
public class WebServiceGuiceServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(
                /* your guice modules */
                new HessianWebServicesModule("your web service implementations package")
        );
    }
}
```

or the manual way using the EDSL:

```
public class WebServiceGuiceServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(
                /* your guice modules */
                new HessianWebServicesModule(){
                    @Override
                    protected void configureHessianWebServices() {
                        serveHessianWebService(UserService.class).usingUrl("/Users");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

More information, configuration options and complete examples are available here: https://bitbucket.org/richard_hauswald/hessian-guice/